# App Transport Security in Simulator

Tags: ssl, ios9, xcode7

I am trying to connect to http://localhost with the simulator for debugging. Since iOS 9 there is App Transport Security enabled and all Connections without TLS 1.2 are getting blocked.

Is there a way to allow connections only for this URL in DEBUG-Builds without adding another target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following property to your application's plist file to allow the connection for development:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to only activate it for debug-builds

Comment: I saw a solution for debug-builds only on this website. Does that help? http://product.reverb.com/2015/06/29/ios-9-and-charles-proxy/